# Passing props with Navlink in react-router-dom (v6)

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

In version 5, I used to do this:

```
<NavLink
  key={"myRoute"}
  to={{
    pathname: "myRoute",
    state: {myState: "myStateValue"},
  }}
  className="nav-card"
>
```

then receive props with `useLocation` `location.state`

But what happened when I upgraded to version 6 is that `location.state` is `null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
<NavLink
  key={"myRoute"}
  to="myRoute"
  state={{ myState: "myStateValue" }}
  className="nav-card"
>
```

then to receive the props:

```
const location = useLocation()
const { myState } = location.state
```