# How to pass props to component with NavLink

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, routes, react-props

I am trying to send props to component with NavLink.

```
 <NavLink to={{pathname :"/wind", state:{from: "This is my props"}}} >Wind</NavLink>
```

and I want to get it in this component,

```
import React from 'react';
import { useLocation} from "react-router-dom"

const Wind = () =>{
    const location = useLocation();
    const {from} = location.state;
    console.log({from})

  return (
    <div className="Wind">
      <h1>Wind</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Wind;
```

unfortunatelly this give me result [image]

so I try it like this

```
import React from 'react';

const Wind = (props) =>{

//console.log(props.location.state)

  return (
    <div className="Wind">
      <h1>Wind</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Wind;
```

console log in ths case is undefined.
I don´t know why it is not working any ideas?

Comment: This ticket is a duplicate, you can refer to
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70054635/passing-props-with-navlink-in-react-router-dom-v6 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59701050/how-to-pass-data-from-a-page-to-another-page-using-react-router

Comment: I saw it but I am still getting the same error "Cannot read properties of null"

Comment: Firstly, which react-router-dom version you are using. And can you share more about this code maybe there is some other issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the new version, the state is passed as a separate prop. Try using

```
<NavLink to={{pathname :"/wind"}}
 state={{from: "This is my props"}} >Wind</NavLink>
```

And the component try fetching like this

```
import React from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const Wind = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const { state } = location;
  console.log(state.from);

  return (
    <div className="Wind">
      <h1>Wind</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Wind;
```

Comment: and how the component should look like? How I display it in component?

Comment: updated my answer try this out.

Comment: that is workig very well but what if I want to send more props something like this doesn´t work and it always see only first data ""state={{ fromTemperature: data, dailyForecast:dataWeather.daily }}""

Comment: you can fetch all the data from your state object. try console.log(state) you should get all the data of that object.